# Iterate Through Multiple XPath Results - Create ONLY ONE NODE

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following example XML:

```
<Example>
        <SiteCode null="no">1ExampleSite</SiteCode>
        <SiteName null="yes"/>
        <CustomerPIN null="no">1234567</CustomerPIN>
        <CustomerLastName null="no">Test </CustomerLastName>
        <CustomerFirstName null="no">Example</CustomerFirstName>
        <CustomerMiddleName null="yes"/>
        <CustomerDOB null="no">2000-01-01 00:00:00.000</CustomerDOB> 
        <CustomerAddressLine1 null="no">1234 Easy ST</CustomerAddressLine1>
        <CustomerAddressLine2 null="yes"/>
        <CustomerCity null="no">Hartford</CustomerCity>
        <CustomerState null="no">CT</CustomerState>
        <CustomerZipCode null="no">123456</CustomerZipCode>
        <CustomerGender null="no">F</CustomerGender>
        <CustomerRaceCode null="no">White</CustomerRaceCode>
        <CustomerRaceName null="yes"/>
</Example>
```

What I WANT to do, is to output XML so that the Address nodes are shared under HomeAddress/Address, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Information>
<PIN>1234567</PIN>
<LastName>Test </LastName>
<FirstName>Example</FirstName>
<MiddleName/>
<DateOfBirth><DateNode>2000-01-01 00:00:00.000</DateNode></DateOfBirth>
<HomeAddress>
  <Address>
   <AddressLine1>1234 Easy ST</AddressLine1>
   <AddressLine2/>
   <City>Hartford</City>
   <State>CT</State>
   <ZipCode>123456</ZipCode>
  </Address>
</HomeAddress>
<Gender><Code>F</Code></Gender>
<RaceCode>White</RaceCode>
<RaceName/>
</Information>
```

This is my current XSLT code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0">

  <xsl:template match="/Example">
    <Information>
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
            <xsl:apply-templates select=".[starts-with(local-name(), 'CustomerGender')]"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select=".[starts-with(local-name(), 'CustomerDOB')]"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select=".[starts-with(local-name(), 'CustomerAddress')
                      or starts-with(local-name(), 'CustomerCity')
                      or starts-with(local-name(), 'CustomerState')
                      or starts-with(local-name(), 'CustomerZipCode')][1]"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select=".[starts-with(local-name(), 'Customer')
             and not(contains(local-name(), 'Gender'))
             and not(contains(local-name(), 'Address'))
             and not(contains(local-name(), 'City'))
             and not(contains(local-name(), 'State'))
             and not(contains(local-name(), 'ZipCode'))
             and not(contains(local-name(), 'DOB'))]"/>
            
                        
                    </xsl:for-each>
      </Information>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match=".[starts-with(local-name(), 'Customer')]">
  <xsl:element name="{replace(local-name(), 'Customer', '')}">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match=".[starts-with(local-name(), 'CustomerGender')]">
  <xsl:element name="{replace(local-name(), 'Customer', '')}">
    <Code>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </Code>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match=".[starts-with(local-name(), 'CustomerDOB')]">
  <DateOfBirth>
    <DateNode>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </DateNode>
  </DateOfBirth>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match=".[starts-with(local-name(), 'CustomerAddress')
                      or starts-with(local-name(), 'CustomerCity')
                      or starts-with(local-name(), 'CustomerState')
                      or starts-with(local-name(), 'CustomerZipCode')]">
  <HomeAddress>
    <Address>
    <xsl:for-each select=".">
    <xsl:element name="{replace(local-name(), 'Customer', '')}">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </Address>
  </HomeAddress>
</xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Yet - here is my current output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Information>
<PIN>1234567</PIN>
<LastName>Test </LastName>
<FirstName>Example</FirstName>
<MiddleName/>
<DateOfBirth><DateNode>2000-01-01 00:00:00.000</DateNode></DateOfBirth>
<Gender><Code>F</Code></Gender>
<RaceCode>White</RaceCode>
<RaceName/>
<HomeAddress><Address><AddressLine1>1234 Easy ST</AddressLine1></Address></HomeAddress><HomeAddress><Address><AddressLine2/></Address></HomeAddress>
<HomeAddress><Address><City>Hartford</City></Address></HomeAddress>
<HomeAddress><Address><State>CT</State></Address></HomeAddress>
<HomeAddress><Address><ZipCode>123456</ZipCode></Address></HomeAddress>
</Information>
```

How can I change this XSL logic so that I get the desired output (the shared "Address" node) instead of the current (multiple "Address" nodes)?

I'll appreciate any help on this, it's possible I overlooked a previous example, but I tried searching and couldn't find anything specific to this scenario.

EDIT: I understand that one can extract the "Address" information outside of the "for-each" I have, like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="*">
            <xsl:apply-templates select=".[starts-with(local-name(), 'CustomerGender')]"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select=".[starts-with(local-name(), 'CustomerDOB')]"/>
            
            <xsl:apply-templates select=".[starts-with(local-name(), 'Customer')
             and not(contains(local-name(), 'Gender'))
             and not(contains(local-name(), 'Address'))
             and not(contains(local-name(), 'City'))
             and not(contains(local-name(), 'State'))
             and not(contains(local-name(), 'ZipCode'))
             and not(contains(local-name(), 'DOB'))]"/>
            
                        
                    </xsl:for-each>

        <HomeAddress>
            <Address>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[starts-with(local-name(), 'CustomerAddress')
                      or starts-with(local-name(), 'CustomerCity')
                      or starts-with(local-name(), 'CustomerState')
                      or starts-with(local-name(), 'CustomerZipCode')]"/>
            </Address>
        </HomeAddress>
```

However, I want to also preserve the order of the data. If the customer address information is in the middle of the data, I want it to appear as such in the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a reason why you cannot do simply:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/Example">
    <xsl:variable name="addr" select="CustomerAddressLine1 | CustomerAddressLine2 | CustomerCity | CustomerState | CustomerZipCode" />
    <Information>
        <xsl:copy-of select="* except $addr"/>
        <HomeAddress>
            <Address>
                <xsl:copy-of select="$addr"/>
            </Address>
        </HomeAddress>
    </Information>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

### Added:

Assuming that the address fields are always in a contiguous block, the expected output could be produced using:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/Example">
    <xsl:variable name="addr" select="CustomerAddressLine1 | CustomerAddressLine2 | CustomerCity | CustomerState | CustomerZipCode" />
    <Information>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$addr[1]/preceding-sibling::*[starts-with(name(), 'Customer')]"/>
        <HomeAddress>
            <Address>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$addr" />
            </Address>
        </HomeAddress>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$addr[last()]/following-sibling::*[starts-with(name(), 'Customer')]"/>
    </Information>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{substring-after(name(), 'Customer')}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="CustomerGender">
    <Gender>
        <Code>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </Code>
  </Gender>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="CustomerDOB">
    <DateOfBirth>
        <DateNode>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </DateNode>
  </DateOfBirth>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I want to still rename nodes to take "Customer" out of the name. I also want to preserve the order of the original XML data, if possible.

Comment: @KieranOjakangas you example output still has the "Customer" in the element names.

Comment: It does for you Sebastien? Interesting. I'm using the Saxon JS parser in VS Code, my output doesn't have "Customer" anywhere due to the second template match statement in my example XSL code at the top of the post.

Comment: @KieranOjakangas Please edit your question and show the exact and complete result you want to get for the given example. As for preserving the order, that can only work if all the address nodes are in a contiguous block in the input XML. Will that always be the case?

Comment: Thanks @michael.hor257k. Edited the post. For all purposes, yes, these address nodes are in a contiguous block together.

Comment: See if the added part makes sense.

Comment: @michael.hor257k thanks so much! For the purpose of this need, this worked beautifully. Very straightforward and elegant!